# Algorithm to Calculate "Best" Option Based on Score

Tags: algorithm

I have an essentially infinite set of "challenges", and each one can be solved (or not) using a formula that has a finite set of inputs, each with a finite set of possible values (so that a possible solution to one challenge might be X=10, Y=22, Z=6, and another might be X=3, Y=14, Z=5). Whether or not a challenge is solved by a particular solution is not known until after the formula is applied to the given challenge. At that point, I will know if the challenge was solved or not.

There are some extra factors to consider:
1) Each iteration of the formula takes time and costs money, so I can't use "brute force" and just try every combination.
2) Over time, a solution that used to work may stop working, and vice versa.
3) There is usually more than one solution to a given challenge.
4) Different solutions have varying time and cost factors, so in the absence of any prior attempts at solving a particular challenge, there is a "known order" of solutions, sorted by these factors.

Each time a challenge is presented, I have access to a history of the prior attempts at solving prior challenges with identical attributes. So after I see a particular challenge a few times, I know what solution has and hasn't worked in the past.

The objective is to take the results of the past challenges (with identical attributes) and prioritize the available solutions in the order that they are most likely to succeed. In a highly simplified version of this: If solution 10/22/6 worked 3 of the last 5 times (and no other previously-attempted solutions worked more than 2 times), then solution 10/22/6 is probably the best one to try first; etc.

*PS - I'm not expecting anyone to "write this" for me; just hoping for some ideas as to what to explore and experiment with. I can't imagine something like this hasn't been done before.*

Comment: You never managed to ask a question.

Comment: Well, my question is "Given a finite set of solutions to a problem, and having a history of the success or failure of certain solutions to an identical problem, what method/process/algorithm would let me prioritize the solutions to try the ones most likely to succeed first?"

Comment: Correction: ...solutions to an _almost_ identical problem... This is the complexity here--each new problem won't be exactly the same as the problems I have history for, because not all of the problem attributes can be known at the time the new problem is received (I know _most_ of the problem attributes, so I can do a reasonable match to a similar problem that I do have history for). The objective is to reduce the number of solutions that have to be tried by trying the ones first that have succeeded most of the time in the past for _almost-identical_ problems.